# javascript - using Proxy trap when instantiating an object

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a javascript function that I can instantiate, and catch every undefined method that is being called to it (Proxy Trap).

What I have so far is this:

```
var MyProxyFunction = new Proxy(function () {
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> constructor");
    }, {
    get: function(target, prop) {
        if (target[prop] === undefined) {
            return function()  {
                console.log('an otherwise undefined function!!');
            };
        }
        else {
            return target[prop];
        }
    }
});
```

Now, if I call `MyProxyFunction.foo()`, it will get called (I will see the "constructor" firing off and the log from the get function).

But what I would like to do is have this object instantiated (and do some initialization in the constructor) like this:

```
var myObj = new MyProxyFunction();
myObj.foo();
```

But when I do that than I get that `foo()` is not a function. Why? and how can I make it work when instantiating the proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation for that behaviour is that your *constructor* is proxied, but not the objects it constructs. So when you write `new MyProxyFunction` the proxied constructor is called, but the constructor creates a new object which has nothing to do with `Proxy`, but with the `prototype` property of the constructor.

There are several ways to make it work.

#### 1. Apply the proxy on the prototype object

```js
function MyProxyFunction() {
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> constructor");
};

MyProxyFunction.prototype = new Proxy(MyProxyFunction.prototype, {
    get: function(target, prop) {
        if (target[prop] === undefined) {
            return function()  {
                console.log('an otherwise undefined function!!');
            };
        }
        else {
            return target[prop];
        }
    }
});

var myObj = new MyProxyFunction();
myObj.foo();
console.log('constructor:', myObj.constructor.name);
console.log('Is instance of MyProxyFunction?: ', myObj instanceof MyProxyFunction);
```

It now looks a bit strange to use the name *MyProxyFunction*, as it is not the function (the constructor) itself that is proxied.

#### 2. Create a proxy for each instance

If you want to have a constructor that creates a new proxy each time you instantiate an object with it, then don't assign `new Proxy` directly to `MyProxyFunction`, but make it a plain constructor function that returns a `new Proxy`.

The object you then have to proxy is `this`.

```js
function MyProxyFunction() {
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> constructor");
    return new Proxy(this, {
        get: function(target, prop) {
            if (target[prop] === undefined) {
                return function()  {
                    console.log('an otherwise undefined function!!');
                };
            }
            else {
                return target[prop];
            }
        }
    });
}
var myObj = new MyProxyFunction();
myObj.foo();
console.log('constructor:', myObj.constructor.name);
console.log('Is instance of MyProxyFunction?: ', myObj instanceof MyProxyFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks. But actually I do need that extra new. Since what I need is to be able to create a few different instances of that same function.